# Character falls faster than it rises when I jump, how can I change falling speed?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, gravity

```
void Update () {
    float positionY = transform.position.y;
    int speed = 5;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        print ("Space pressed");
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                                         positionY * speed * Time.deltaTime,
                                         transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

This is a flappy bird type game and I'm using this function to make the character jump when I press space, however when I let go of that key, the character falls much faster than it was falling initially and the more I press space the faster it falls..

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you use gravity to make the bird fall.

What your code does is moving the bird up by changing it position to be higher then its previous position. The bird however still has the original velocity it had before you moved it up. So it keeps on falling. Because it keeps on falling it keeps going faster and faster.

To solve this you have to set the birds velocity to zero after moving it up